# Encoding video files for XNA

Tags: c#, xna, media

How can I encode an AVI to the 'correct' format for XNA? Is there any way to encode video with Windows Live Movie Maker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Live Movie Maker can output video in the format desired by the video content importer in XNA. That is to say, WLMM saves video as Windows Media Video 9 "Main", using the VC-1 video codec and Windows Media Audio 9.2 audio codec. You still need to ensure that you don't go beyond the bounds of bit rate as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254869.aspx), but if you use the "Burn a DVD" settings when saving your movie, you should be just fine if you're doing 480p.

NB: I'm not sure if video without audio will save with an audio track. However, XNA's video importer requires that an audio track is included, or the import will fail. If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to create a second or two of silence as a WAV and include that in your video project, if so required.

Comment: I'm doing 720p, not 480:Edit, The bit rate specifications were useful! I ended up using Microsoft Expression Studio to encode the video.

Comment: Expression Studio is probably the best bet to use anyway. But for those who can't (or won't) shill for it, it's a relief to know that yes, I _can_ use WLMM if I want.

Comment: I decided it's worth the money for this project :)